# NestJS Reconnect to DB after connection was lost

Tags: node.js, database, oracle, nestjs

In NestJS I have a Database module with a factory function that connects to the database and returns the connection object.

```
async function createConnection(dbConfig: DbConfig, libDir: string) {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({
    libDir,
  });

  const connection: Connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

  return connection;
}
```

This object is then injected in the service

```
 @Inject("CONNECTION") private readonly dbConnection: Connection
```

The problem is that the connection can be closed from outside of the application(ex db server restarts).

My assumption is if this happens then the connection object must be reinitialized.

```
const connection: Connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
```

The question is how can this be done in NestJS if the connection is retrieved in factory function and then injected in the service?

Should I overwrite the object that I inject in the service or can I recall the factory function?
What is the best practice here?

**UPDATE**

This is a NestJS question and not a **oracledb** question.
The problem is how can I recall the createConnection function to update the connection object and in this way to update the injected value in the service?

Comment: Which library are you using for the db-connection?

Comment: Hi. I'm using oracledb

Comment: This one https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb ?

Comment: Can you use a node-oracledb connection pool.  And make sure you get/close the connection at appropriate times?  The connection pool will automatically handle reconnection in a number of cases when you get the connection from the pool.

Comment: Hi Jones. The problem is that I don't want to cerate a connection pool, but rather to use one from the existing pools. What I want is to know if there is any way in NestJS to reset the module or update the injected connection object by recalling the createConnection function.